# Convert a query result to hstore

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I am using PostgreSQL 9.4. I need to convert subquery to hstore.
I have this query: `select code, value_string from dir`. It returns

```
code  | value_string
------|--------------
CODE  | 1
ACC   | 2
...
```

How to convert his result to `hstore('"ACC"=>"2", "CODE"=>"1", ...')`?

I am looking something like this: `SELECT hstore(select code, value_string from dir)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html):

> `hstore(text[], text[])` - construct an hstore from separate key and value arrays.

Use `array_agg()` as arguments for this function. Example:

```
create table dir (code text, value_string text);
insert into dir values
('CODE', 1),
('ACC', 2);

select hstore(array_agg(code), array_agg(value_string))
from dir;

         hstore          
-------------------------
 "ACC"=>"2", "CODE"=>"1"
(1 row)
```